# trac-admin with svn post-commit hook causes segmentation fault

Tags: linux, svn, trac, svn-hooks

I just set up trac 0.12.2 over sqlite on my Fedora box and trac is working fine through the web browser and command line. My issue is with implementing svn hooks where the post-commit hook dies on a segmentation fault when running this command:

`/usr/bin/trac-admin /var/trac/myproject changeset added "$1" "$2"`

Where $1 is the svn repository path on the local file system and $2 is the revision.

The output of this command is this:

`/path/to/svn/hooks/post-commit: line 9:  3874 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/trac-admin /var/trac/myproject changeset added "$1" "$2"`

How would I go about debugging this? Does anyone know why this might be happening on a fresh install (I did not upgrade, it's clean)?

I did some basic checking with regards to the user running this command which is `apache`. I also tried running this command as `apache` to see if it would fail, but this works just find from the command line:

`sudo -u apache /usr/bin/trac-admin /var/trac/ujaweb changeset added /path/to/svn/repo 750`

I'm somewhat out of ideas here. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

*Here is some further information in case it's useful:*

Linux: Linux hostname.com 2.6.18-028stab069.5 #1 SMP Tue May 18 17:26:16 MSD 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Apache: 2.2.17 w/ mod_wsgi
Python: 2.6.4
Trac: 0.12.2 (over Apache w/ mod_wsgi)

Comment: Here's an strace output of the run: http://205.186.157.63/strace.tgz

Answer (score 1):

You could try running `trac-admin` under `strace`, and save the output:

```
/usr/bin/strace -o /var/trac/myproject/log/trace.log /usr/bin/trac-admin /var/trac/myproject changeset added "$1" "$2"
```

Then, have a look at the generated log in `/var/trac/myproject/log/trace.log`.

Another option would be to have your system generate a core dump (you may have to enable it in your `/etc/limits` and/or `/etc/security/limits.conf`), and open the dump with `gdb`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's unclear to me, however what may have cause the fault. I tgzipped it and it's available here: http://205.186.157.63/strace.tgz -- Now, it looks like munmap(0x2b4850bb7000, 4096) fails after having opened open("/proc/mounts", O_RDONLY). I'm not certain what this means. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't fail at the munmap(), but right afterward. I see two suspects in the trace: a reference to /selinux and a vzfs filesystem. Also, in the last few lines, there are EPERM and EACCESS errors when trying to create temporary files in /tmp, /var/tmp and /dev/shm. You may want to check your security policies and permissions, and ensure that you can create temporary files.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Creating files in /tmp and /var/tmp succeeds, it's the mmap() that fail, with EPERM. The mmap() manpage has the following to say about this: "The prot argument asks for PROT_EXEC but the mapped area belongs to a file on a file system that was mounted no-exec." So you should mount /tmp with the "exec" option.

Comment: ... or find out what creates the temporary files and requests mmap()ing them with PROT_EXEC. It could be related to ctypes, see http://bugs.python.org/issue5504.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm trying to re-mount tmp and I get "mount: permission denied" (yes, I'm running as root), so it's a bit frustrating. Now I'm going to try to figure this out, too...

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be to turn off the selinux for a while and test if it still happens.
If not - you have to figure out how to configure selinux to allow opening /proc/mount by that process failing with segmentation fault.

Comment: It doesn't appear that SElinux is running. The file /usr/sbin/getenforce does not exist, there is no configs in /etc/sysconfig, and the /selinux directory in root is empty.